# Getting Context.User.Identity.Name Null After Event Got Fire of SqlDependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr, sqldependency

I have first time implemented signalR concept and its working when page load first time and when I perform any insert,  delete or updated operation on the database it calls a method which is specified in code but I am getting the null value of Context.User.Identity.Name. I have used FormAuthentication and after logged in I am getting connectionId and username but after make changes on a table of database getting the null value of username. Below I have mentioned my code.

### HubClass

```
 namespace SCPLTabAssessPortal
{
  public class User
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; }
  }
  [Authorize]
  public class DashboardNewHub : Hub
  {
     int totalNewMessages = 0;
     int ttltdy = 0;
     int Ttlnum = 0;
     int totalNewNotification = 0;
     private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();
     public override Task OnConnected()
     {            
         string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;           
         string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
         var user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new User
         {
             Name = userName,
             ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
         });           
         lock (user.ConnectionIds)
         {
             user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
Clients.AllExcept(user.ConnectionIds.ToArray()).userConnected(userName);
                // TODO: Broadcast the connected user
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
       }
 public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        User rmuser;
        Users.TryRemove(name, out rmuser);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;           
        var user = Users.GetOrAdd(name, _ => new User
        {
            Name = name,
            ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
        });
        lock (user.ConnectionIds)
        {
            user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
            Clients.AllExcept(user.ConnectionIds.ToArray()).userConnected(name);
            // TODO: Broadcast the connected user
        }           
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
[HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
    public string SendNotifications()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> allReceivers = null;
        try
        {
User getuser = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);                
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCPLDBPortalConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {                    
                string query = "SELECT [ColumnName],[ColumnName] FROM [dbo].[TableName] ";
                connection.Open();
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Notification = null;
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            connection.Open();
                        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        dt.Load(reader);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
 int totaltax = 0;
                            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                totaltax += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(r["TaxTotal"])) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(r["TaxTotal"]));
                            }
                            totalNewMessages = totaltax;
                        }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
 catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
User receiver;               
            if (Users.TryGetValue(getuser.Name, out receiver))
            {
                User sender = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
                lock (receiver.ConnectionIds)
                {
                    lock (sender.ConnectionIds)
                    {
                        allReceivers = receiver.ConnectionIds.Concat(sender.ConnectionIds);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var cid in allReceivers)
                {
                    Clients.Client(cid).received(totalNewMessages);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {              
        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DashboardNewHub>();
        return (string)context.Clients.Client(Convert.ToString(allReceivers.Last())).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages).Result;
    }
 private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            DashboardNewHub nHub = new DashboardNewHub();
            nHub.SendNotifications();                
        }
    }
    private User GetUser(string username)
    {
        User user;
        Users.TryGetValue(username, out user);
        return user;
    }
}   
}
```

### JqueryCode

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {                            
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var notifications = $.connection.dashboardNewHub;               
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages, ttltdy) {
                $('#TtlColl').text(totalNewMessages);                   
            };               
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                notifications.server.sendNotifications();

            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
  });
```

### Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);          
    }

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

### Login.cs

The below code I wrote while a user is logging in.

```
 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text + "$" + DS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Who is triggering the dependency_onChange event? Not the logged in user but the sql broker engine.

Comment: sql broker engine

Answer (score 0):

The point is because is the sql broker engine to call  `nHub.SendNotifications()`  you can't get any informations about the user logged-in as is not the user logged is making the request

Comment: Means are you suggesting me to pass parameter inside of nHub.SendNotifications() is it?

Comment: Users.TryGetValue(getuser.Name, out receiver) is where you get the problem as getuser.Name is null true? What is the purpose of Users.TryGetValue(getuser.Name, out receiver)?  to discover the consignee of you message? True?

Comment: at this line i am getting error "User getuser = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);" but when i am getting null when i make changes on table of database